# Dynamic form using HTML and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a dynamic form using HTML and CSS. I am adding parts of my code below. I can not figure out why the code is not working.

JavaScript:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var labelfiled = '<div><label>Label</label><input type="text" name="label[]"></div>';
    var valuefiled = '<div><label>Value</label><input type="text" name="value[]"></div>';
    var labdiv = $(".labdiv");
    var valdiv = $(".valdiv");
    var addbutton = $(".add_more");
    $(addbutton).click(function(){
            $(labdiv).append(labelfiled);
            $(valdiv).append(valuefield);
    });
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="col-md-6 labdiv">
<div><label>Label</label>
<input type="text" name="label[]">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 valdiv">
<div>
<label>Value</label>
<input type="text" name="value[]">
</div>
</div>
<button class="add_more">Add values</button>
</form>
```

If someone can help it would be great.

I also would like to know how I can process the data when I submit this into a javascript variable in the from of a array. Like for example if i have 2 inputs for value in the from, I want to store them in a javascript array and then convert it into a JSON.

Comment: You get any errors in your console? You're missing `});` at the end of your script tag to close your `$(document).ready()` call.

Comment: To supplement lexith's comment: *that* is why code-indentation is a beautiful thing.

Comment: @lexith hi, i am new to web development and i dont know where i can see the console from. p.s i am using adove dreamweaver for making this.

Answer (score 0):

Form must be in method="POST" and if you get in into php function :

```
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST){ /*try something with $_POST*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".add_more").click(function() {
                   var postData = {
                        field1: $("#id_field1").val(),
                        field2: $("#id_field2").val()
                    };

    $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            data:JSON.stringify(postData),
            url: URL,
            method: 'POST'
        });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

*A few things that may improve your learning:*

> ***jQuery and you code***

All jQuery code should be wrapped in this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // jQuery
});
```

On the `var`'s you have created, you have already initialised them as jQuery elements. Therefore, when you reference them again, you do not need (for example) *$(addbutton)* as *addbutton* will do. *See amended code below)*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var labelfiled = '<div><label>Label</label><input type="text" name="label[]"></div>';
        var valuefiled = '<div><label>Value</label><input type="text" name="value[]"></div>';
        var labdiv = $(".labdiv");
        var valdiv = $(".valdiv");
        var addbutton = $(".add_more");
        addbutton.click(function(){
            labdiv.append(labelfiled);
            valdiv.append(valuefield);
        });
    });
</script>
```

> ***The console***

On checking the console...

Say, for example, if you write the JS code `console.log(1 + 1)` in your page somewhere as you want to see that sum. Due to you writing client side code, when your web page loads (and depending where you have put the `console.log()`) if you check the **developer tools** in your chosen browser i.e. Chrome or IE, there is a `console` section where you can see the result of what you printed (i.e. using that example, it would be 2). This `console` in the browser will also print out errors that it detects (i.e. `$ is not defined` - if you are trying to reference jQuery but the library isn't included), it's a good tool for web developers (hence the name ;)) for debugging client side code.

> ***Adding elements to array***

Code for getting `input` values on submit of a form: *(jQuery)*

```
var array = [];
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
        array.push($(this).val();
    });
});
```

I would suggest that you go and read a book/tutorial on jQuery code as well as the basic concepts of web development :)

Examples:

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

For reference to basics if you get stuck, the link above is more reliable:
 - [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)

Comment: Consider removing references to w3schools since it's nothing official and by far the worst documentation-like page one can find. Why? Because: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: That post mentions that w3schools has improved over the past year or so. I am not suggesting to OP to use the site religiously. I am merely suggesting a site for reference of the basics. I believe OP will find parts of the site useful as they are a beginner

Comment: I have edited my answer to add additional reasoning behind the links

Comment: They might have improved, but still it's not the best site to quote. Maybe you want to go with something more reliable like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web for general HTML / CSS / Javascript reference and like you already did, explicitly refer to the official documentation of a tool / plugin (or whatever) like jQuery.
Just an advice, no offense :)